# a NOR-3 gate made only by NOR-2s

Tags: logic

i was curious if it is possible you can make a 3 input nor gate just by using usual 2-input nor gates, but it seems like there's always one source that, no matter what the other two are, it has the same result. 
[image]

is there a way that this is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211756/how-to-build-a-3-input-nand-gate-from-2-input-nand-gates-or-a-3-input-nor-gate-f